# Retrieving Nested Data from Firebase for a Website

Tags: javascript, html, web, firebase-realtime-database

[This is how my html looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnDT7.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pet Article</title>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.8/firebase.js"></script>

</head>



<body>

 
 <img src = "cat.jpg" width = 700px , height = "500px" />
 <img src = "dog.jpg" width = 700px , height = "500px" />

 <p>This is the paragraph <br /> Need more?</p>
 <hr />
 
 <h1 id="big0ne" ></h1> 
 
 <script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  
  var big0ne = document.getElementById('big0ne');
  var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('text');
  dbRef.on('value', snap => big0ne.innerText = snap.val());
   
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

I am a newbie in programming and this is the first time I would ask here so please bear with me.

We were asked to make a project using firebase database and connect it to our website to retrieve data. I have found tutorials on youtube and the internet, however i cant seem to find a tutorial that works on retrieving nested value on firebase. It returns the data as
[object Object]

I would like to know how to retrieve nested data in firebase. I would attach the image of how my database looks like. heres my html code. I didnt make a separate javascript file. I just put the javascript code inside the "script" tag since it works anyways. I will purposely remove API keys, etc. for security reasons.

[image]

Comment: Please don't add question details in answer, edit your question for that.

Comment: sorry about that. I already edited my post.

Comment: Not an answer, but a quick reminder that sharing the Firebase configuration data is not necessarily a security risk. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You right now have the following code to read from Firbase:

```
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('text');
dbRef.on('value', snap => big0ne.innerText = snap.val());
```

This reads the value of the `text` node and you then take its value with `val()`. Looking at the JSON screenshot you shared, the value of `text` is:

```
{
  "text2": "Wonder Pets"
}
```

This is itself a JavaScript object, so if you call `toString()` on it (which your code implicitly does) you get `"[object Object]"` (or some variant of that, depending on the browser).

To get the value of the `text2` child node, you should use:

```
big0ne.innerText = snap.child("text2").val()
```

So in the above line, we take the `text2` child node of the snapshot and then value of that, which is exactly the string you want.

Comment: Thanks alot this worked. What will I do if for example text2 has another child node? For Example "text>text2>text3 : Wonder Pets"... and so on? Basically I'm asking what will I use if I need more nested data such as "text 4 or text 5".

Comment: `snap.child("text2").child("text3").val()` or `snap.child("text2/text3").val()`, etc